# NLog initial send and multiple bulk emailing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

**Background**

I have a web application written in asp.net core v2.2. I use NLog as my 3rd party logger which emails me each time there's an application error which works well.

```xml
    <targets>
       <!--eg email on error -->
        <target xsi:type="Mail"
                  name="emailnotify"
                  header="An Error has been reported By foo.com (${machinename}) ${newline}  "
                  layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true:padding=5} - ${logger:shortName=true} - ${message} ${exception:format=tostring} ${newline}"
                  html="true"
                  addNewLines="true"
                  replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml="true"
                  subject="Error on foo.com (${machinename})"
                  to="foo@foo.com"
                  from="foo@foo.com"
                  secureSocketOption="StartTls"
                  smtpAuthentication="basic"
                  smtpServer="${environment:EmailConfigNlogSMTPServer}"
                  smtpPort="25"
               smtpusername="${environment:EmailConfigNlogSMTPUsername}"
                smtppassword="${environment:EmailConfigNlogSMTPPassword}" />
        <!-- set up a blackhole log catcher -->
        <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />
    </targets>

     <rules>
        <!-- Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" level="Info" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
        <!-- Send errors via emailnotify target -->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="emailnotify" final="true" />
      </rules>
```

However, there are times when a large amount of emails, in short succession could come in, making me feel like I'm being "spammed", before I've had chance to resolve the issue.

1. An example could be on rare occasions such as my application's 3rd party search engine being down. At this point every user doing a search on the website would generate an error resulting in a potentially large number of emails.
2. Another example is when speculative 404s are occurring either by companies gathering website technology statistics or just plain dodgy requests. i.e. /bitcoin/xxx or /shop/xxx or git/.head/xxx.

Historically, I've used the "filters" feature around some of the 404s I was receiving and have set some up. See example below. However, in bulk format, I want to be notified about all 404s or 500s. I don't feel it's a good idea trying to filter things out that don't seem relevant as you can start missing out on key information such as hacking attempts, SQL injection attacks or application sniffing:

```xml
    <filters>
        <when condition="contains('${message}','.php')" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="contains('${message}','wp-includes')" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="contains('${message}','wordpress')" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="contains('${message}','downloader')" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
```

**Requirement**

I want to introduce the following logic into my application logging:

1. Email notify when the first 500 error of type occurs (i.e error performing search on website, error accessing database) so I know straight away the first time the application has the initial error
2. Bulk notify consecutive 500 errors after the initial error so I know when else this error occurred but it won't continue to "spam" me.
3. Bulk notify all 404, 405 errors

These bulk emails would notify me after 50 errors or once a day whichever comes first.

Ideally, I would like the format of the bulk email to be:

*Bulk email*

Subject: 500 errors (13) | 404 errors (2)

Body in a table format:

```
500 Errors (13)
-----------------------------------------------------
| When                 | Message                    |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:29  | Website search engine down |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:30  | Website search engine down |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:31  | Website search engine down |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:32  | Website search engine down |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:33  | Website search engine down |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:34  | Website search engine down |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:35  | Website search engine down |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:11:01  | Login failed for user foo  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:11:01  | Login failed for user foo  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:11:01  | Login failed for user foo  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:11:02  | Login failed for user foo  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:11:02  | Login failed for user foo  |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:11:02  | Login failed for user foo  |
-----------------------------------------------------    

404 Errors (2)
-----------------------------------------------------
| When                 | Message                    |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:45  | /bitcoin not found         |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 2019-11-13 11:10:57  | /shop not found            |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Alternatively, I'd be happy to have separate bulk emails for the 500s, 404s or 405s.

In the example bulk email above, the application would've informed me straight away with 2 separate emails that there was an issue

1. With the website search engine being down
2. The user not being able to access the SQL database

And then after hitting 50 errors or once a day, send out the bulk email.

**Question**

Is my requirement possible using just NLog configuration?

I can see how I can carry out bulk notification using NLog's [buffer wrapper](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target) configuration, although I don't think it's possible to output in the table format I'd ideally like.

```xml
      <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
              name="bulkemailnotify"
              bufferSize="50"
              flushTimeout="86400000‬"
              slidingTimeout="False"
              overflowAction="Flush">
        <target xsi:type="emailnotify" />
      </target>
```

If not, would it be looking at one of the following?

1. [Extending NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending-NLog)
2. [Removing NLog and adding a custom logger](https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/05/add-custom-logging-in-aspnetcore.html)

Ideally, I would continue to use NLog and would only look to add a custom logger as a last resort.

Comment: Check this target wrapper: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/LimitingWrapper-target :)

Comment: Thanks for that @Julian. My only concern with using that is if I set this up (say 50 an hour), if something like my 3rd party search engine went down, the 50 logs could be used up in a couple of minutes and I could be missing out on important logs for the remaining 58 minutes? Or could this somehow be coupled with other targets so this information isn't missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say that `${aspnet-response-statuscode}` is the one returning the HTTP Status Code:

Then we can have following two targets:

- Instant mail-target with first error (instant trigger with first event, and waits 5 min before triggering again)
- Bulk mail-target with all errors (triggers after 5 min with all events)

Then you could probably do this:

```xml
<targets async="true">
   <target xsi:type="SplitGroup" name="special-mail">
       <target xsi:type="FilteringWrapper" name="filter-mail">
          <filter type="whenRepeated" layout="${aspnet-response-statuscode}" timeoutSeconds="300" action="Ignore" />
          <target xsi:type="Mail" name="instant-mail">
                 <header>Instant Error Report</header>
          </target>
       </target>
       <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="buffer-mail" flushTimeout="300000">
           <target xsi:type="Mail" name="bulk-mail">
                <header>Bulk Error Report</header>
           </target>
       </target>
   </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="special-mail" final="true" />
</rules>
```

Not that skilled with the mail-target-layouts (header + body + footer) and making a good looking html-email. But you can probably steal something from the internet.

Comment: Thank you @Rolf Kristensen, I'll give what you've suggested a go. On the face of it, it looks to be a major chunk of the way to what I need!

Comment: @Neil Happy that NLog could handle the task. Thank you for sharing the complete solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58994035/193178

Answer (score 2):

I've marked @Rolf Kristensen's answer as the answer because he gave me a large chunk of the functionality I asked for.

However, I thought I'd share what my final config looked like in case this can help anyone else.

Ideally, I wanted to use the ${exception:format=HResult} to check for a repeating log in the "whenRepeated" filter but there's a bug which has been fixed in a future release of nlog.

**Edit:** Updated the `WhenRepeated` attribute of the `<filter>` to include `${exception:format=TargetSite} ${exception:format=Type}` as per Rolf Kristensen's recommendation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal.txt">

  <!-- We're using the Mail xsi:type so reference mailkit -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.MailKit"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- Set up the variables that we want to use across the various email targets -->
  <variable name="exceptiontostring" value="${exception:format=tostring}" />
  <variable name="abbreviatedenvironment" value="${left:inner=${environment:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}:length=1}" />
  <variable name="websiteshortname" value="${configsetting:cached=True:name=WebsiteConfig.ShortName}" />
  <!-- If you change the below value, ensure you update the nummillisecondstobufferkeyerrors variable too -->
  <variable name="numsecondstobufferkeyerrors" value="10" />
  <!-- This should always be set to the value of numsecondstobufferkeyerrors variable *1000 to ensure initial logs aren't missed being sent -->
  <variable name="nummillisecondstobufferkeyerrors" value="10000" />
  <!-- Set the timings around how often the email the non key error email gets sent. If you want an email once a day, set this to 86400000 -->
  <variable name="nummillisecondstobuffernonkeyerrors" value="5000" />
  <variable name="borderstyle" value="border: 1px solid #000000;" />

  <!-- Define various log targets -->
  <!-- Targets that write info and error logs to a file -->
  <targets async="true">
    <!-- Write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="error" fileName="D:\Dev\dotnet\Core\Logs\Logging2.2\error-log-${shortdate}.log"
                 layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="info" fileName="D:\Dev\dotnet\Core\Logs\Logging2.2\info-log-${shortdate}.log"
                 layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- Targets that send emails -->
  <targets>
    <!-- Ensure we try for up to a minute to resend emails if there's a temporary issue with the email service so we still get to be notified of any logs -->
    <default-wrapper xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
      <wrapper-target xsi:type="RetryingWrapper" retryDelayMilliseconds="6000" retryCount="10" />
    </default-wrapper>

    <!-- Set up the default parameters for each email target so we don't have to repeat them each time -->
    <default-target-parameters xsi:type="Mail">
      <to>${configsetting:cached=True:name=EmailConfig.SendErrorsTo}</to>
      <from>${configsetting:cached=True:name=EmailConfig.FromAddress}</from>
      <secureSocketOption>StartTls</secureSocketOption>
      <smtpAuthentication>basic</smtpAuthentication>
      <smtpServer>${environment:EmailConfigNlogSMTPServer}</smtpServer>
      <smtpPort>25</smtpPort>
      <smtpusername>${environment:EmailConfigNlogSMTPUsername}</smtpusername>
      <smtppassword>${environment:EmailConfigNlogSMTPPassword}</smtppassword>
      <html>true</html>
      <addNewLines>true</addNewLines>
      <replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml>true</replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml>
    </default-target-parameters>

    <!-- Set up a SplitGroup target that allows us to split out key errors between
    1) Sending an initial email notification for each key distinct error
    2) Buffer all key errors and send them later so we don't keep getting the same error multiple times straight away -->
    <target xsi:type="SplitGroup" name="key-error-mail">
      <target xsi:type="FilteringWrapper" name="filter-mail">
        <!-- Ignore any previous logs for the same controller, action and exception
        TO DO: Change ${exception:format=TargetSite} ${exception:format=Type} in the layout below to be ${exception:format=HResult} when bug is fixed -->
        <filter type="whenRepeated" layout="${exception:format=TargetSite} ${exception:format=Type}" timeoutSeconds="${numsecondstobufferkeyerrors}" action="Ignore" />
        <!-- If we get past the ignore filter above then we send the instant mail -->
        <target xsi:type="Mail" name="key-error-instant-mail">
          <subject>Error on ${websiteshortname} (${abbreviatedenvironment}) ${newline}</subject>
          <layout>${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true:padding=5} - ${logger:shortName=true} - ${message} ${exceptiontostring} ${newline}</layout>
        </target>
      </target>
      <!-- Ensure that we buffer all logs to the bulk email -->
      <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="buffer-key-error-mail" flushTimeout="${nummillisecondstobufferkeyerrors}">
        <!-- Send out bulk email of key logs in a table format -->
        <target xsi:type="Mail" name="key-error-bulk-mail">
          <subject>Bulk Key Errors on ${websiteshortname} (${abbreviatedenvironment})</subject>
          <layout>
            &lt;strong&gt;${aspnet-response-statuscode} Error ${when:when='${aspnet-request-url}'!='':inner=on ${aspnet-request-url} (${aspnet-mvc-controller} > ${aspnet-mvc-action})}&lt;/strong&gt;
            &lt;table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="border-collapse:collapse; ${borderstyle}"&gt;
            &lt;thead&gt;
            &lt;tr style="background-color:#cccccc;"&gt;
            &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;Date&lt;/th&gt;
            &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;IP Address&lt;/th&gt;
            &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;User Agent&lt;/th&gt;
            &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;Method&lt;/th&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/thead&gt;
            &lt;tbody&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${longdate}&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${aspnet-request-ip}&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${aspnet-request-useragent}&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${aspnet-request-method}&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan="4" style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${message}&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan="4" style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${exceptiontostring}&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
            &lt;/tbody&gt;&lt;/table&gt;
            ${newline}
          </layout>
        </target>
      </target>
    </target>

    <!-- Set up a non key error buffer wrapper that we're not interested in receiving an immediate notification for
    Send a periodic email with a list of the logs encountered since the last email was sent
    Send the email out in table format -->
    <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="buffer-mail-non-key-error" flushTimeout="${nummillisecondstobuffernonkeyerrors}">
      <target xsi:type="Mail" name="bulk-mail-non-key-error">
        <subject>Bulk Errors on ${websiteshortname} (${abbreviatedenvironment})</subject>
        <layout>
          &lt;strong&gt;${aspnet-response-statuscode} Error ${when:when='${aspnet-request-url}'!='':inner=on ${aspnet-request-url} (${aspnet-mvc-controller} > ${aspnet-mvc-action})}&lt;/strong&gt;
          &lt;table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="border-collapse:collapse; ${borderstyle}"&gt;
          &lt;thead&gt;
          &lt;tr style="background-color:#cccccc;"&gt;
          &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;Date&lt;/th&gt;
          &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;IP Address&lt;/th&gt;
          &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;User Agent&lt;/th&gt;
          &lt;th style="${borderstyle}"&gt;Method&lt;/th&gt;
          &lt;/tr&gt;
          &lt;/thead&gt;
          &lt;tbody&gt;
          &lt;tr&gt;
          &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${longdate}&lt;/td&gt;
          &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${aspnet-request-ip}&lt;/td&gt;
          &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${aspnet-request-useragent}&lt;/td&gt;
          &lt;td style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${aspnet-request-method}&lt;/td&gt;
          &lt;/tr&gt;
          &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan="4" style="${borderstyle}"&gt;${message}&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
          &lt;/tbody&gt;&lt;/table&gt;
          ${newline}
        </layout>
      </target>
    </target>

    <!-- Set up a blackhole log catcher -->
    <target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" level="Info" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
    <!-- Now we've sent Microsoft logs to the blackhole, we only log non Microsoft info to the info log file-->
    <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="info" final="true" />
    <!-- Log errors to the error email buffer and error file -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="error" />
    <!-- log any key errors to the SplitGroup target -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="key-error-mail">
      <filters defaultAction="Log">
        <when condition="starts-with('${aspnet-response-statuscode}','4')" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
    <!-- log any non key errors to the bufferwrapper target -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="buffer-mail-non-key-error">
      <filters defaultAction="Log">
        <when condition="not starts-with('${aspnet-response-statuscode}','4')" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: While waiting for NLog 4.7 to fix `${exception:format=HResult}` then maybe you could use `${exception:format=Type}`

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen, I considered this but ideally wanted the line number to be part of the repeat check to be truly unique, in case there are multiple lines that generate the same error type.From my testing, HResult gave me this unique per error type and line number. I saw from the docs that ${exception:format=tostring} does have an overhead but I want to output this anyway which is why I set it as a variable and used the variable in places I needed. If you see an issue with this, could I use the ${callsite-linenumber:skipFrames=Integer} temporarily until the HResult fix comes in to play?

Comment: What about `${exception:format=TargetSite}` ? But yes nothing beats `${exception:format=tostring}` in being unique.

Comment: Thanks @RolfKristensen, I've updated the WhenRepeating to look at the exception TargetSite and Type combined so, in the unlikely event that one code method gives multiple error types I'll still hear about each of them straight away.